# Limit result size for every matching criteria inside a sunspot/solr any_of block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, lucene, sunspot

I am using solr and sunspot to perform a complex search in a couple million records as such: (simplified for brevity)

```
Model.solr_search do |query|
  query.any_of

    # fairly simple to accomplish with Grouping/Field Collapsing
    with(:age).between(10..20)
    with(:age).between(20..30)

    # trying to limit the number of results I get for the following
    query.all_of do |q|
      q.with(:school_id).any_of(@user.school.id)
      q.with(:graduation_year).between(@user.graduation_year..@user.graduation_year+1)
    end

  end
end
```

What I would like to do is get a pre-defined number of results where age is in between 10 and 20 and age is in between 20 and 30. I would also like to get a pre-determined amount of matches where the school_id is foo and the graduation year is bar.

**I have considered a couple options:**

1. Doing multiple queries, this works if there are only 2 or 3 groups like the example above but in the real-world scenario there will be around 10 (10 solr queries a no bueno).
2. Using Result Grouping/Field Collapsing which will work for the age criteria as I know that during time of index, but I don't think I am able to generate groups based on dynamic params.
3. Somehow flagging the result and filtering out the desired amount later (not sure it is possible).

In case you are wondering I am trying to get 30 results, 10 from each one of the groups. Using SQL is not an options as I would have to query millions of rows.